# How can I abbreviate an ActorRef's path when logging in Akka?

Tags: scala, logging, akka, actor

When I do a `log.info("just a log message")`, I get a log string like this:

```
[INFO] [01/22/2018 18:28:31.950] [s-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://s/user/bob] just a log message
```

where `bob` is the name of the actor reference.

I would like to obtain the following instead:

```
[INFO] [01/22/2018 18:28:31.950] [bob] just a log message
```

How can I do that? How can I configure akka or the logger to not include all that boilerplate information in the log?

Comment: You will need to define a custom logSource for your actors for changing `[akka://s/user/bob]` to `[bob]` - (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/logging.html#translating-log-source-to-string-and-class). And change logback appender config for removing thread name - `[s-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7]` part (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/logging.html#logging-thread-akka-source-and-actor-system-in-mdc).

Comment: The custom logSource idea helped only as long as I did not change the logback appender config for removing the thread name. When I started using the logback slf4j logger instead of Akka's default logger, `%logger{0}` or `%logger` would print the class name and not the shortened actorRef path (i.e. `bob`) that I was generating with my custom logSource.

Comment: you need to use `%akkaSource` in logback appender for the actor name provided by `logSource `.

Comment: This is what I got when I tried to use `%akkaSource`: `[INFO] 18:48:24.471 [%PARSER_ERROR[akkaSource]] just a log message`

Answer (score 3):

While @elm's answer and @Sarvesh's comment put me in the right track, they did not completely answer my question. So, I am posting here a complete solution.

In `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.5.9",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
)
```

In `src/main/resources/reference.conf`:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
}
```

In `src/main/resources/logback.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>[%level] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %message%n%xException{5}</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>log/akka.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Then create `ActorRefLogging.scala`:

```
trait ActorRefLogging { this: Actor =>
  // if self.toString() is "akka://s/user/bob#1234567"
  // then shortName is "bob"
  private val shortName = self.toString().split("/").last.split("#").head
  private val l = Logging(context.system, this)

  object log {
    def error(s: String): Unit = l.error(s"[$shortName] $s")
    def warning(s: String): Unit = l.warning(s"[$shortName] $s")
    def info(s: String): Unit = l.info(s"[$shortName] $s")
    def debug(s: String): Unit = l.debug(s"[$shortName] $s")
  }
}
```

Then mix in the trait in the actor and user the logger:

```
class MyActor extends Actor with ActorRefLogging {
  def receive = {
    case m => log.info(s"Received: $m")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `resources/logback.xml` update `[%logger]` to `[%logger{0}]` for instance as in

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%level] %d{yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%logger{0}] %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: `%logger{0}` shows the class name. How could I modify this to show the actorRef's path instead?